# Minikube: using hyperkit, error buildx component is required?

Tags: docker, minikube

I installed Minikube with the hyperkit driver on MacOS.  When running `docker build` I'm receiving the following errors.  Does anyone know how to resolve them?

```
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/
```

I have only the following `brew` packages installed for docker: `docker`, `docker-buildx`, `docker-completion`, `docker-buildx`.